# How to force Jruby to use inbuilt Ruby 1.9 instead of Ruby 1.8 which is default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I have developed a Ruby on Rails application and successfully deployed on Weblogic using Jruby and Warbler (which creates a war file based on the settings in config/warble.rb).

I believe although Jruby comes with inbuilt Ruby 1.8 and 1.9, by default it uses 1.8 and I want to test the same rails application in Ruby 1.9 within JRuby as I heard that Ruby 1.9 is a lot faster than 1.8. I do not see any configuration option in warble.rb

where we can specify to use Ruby version to use. Whats the best way to force Jruby to use Ruby 1.9?

Also my Rails application is based on Rails 2.3.2, are there any compatability issues on running rails application (built on 2.3.2) on Ruby 1.9? If so will upgrading rails to 2.3.5 solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same question, but with an 'irb' flavor. If I use 'gem install...' the gem is usable in 1.9.2 but not in 1.8.7. Using the jruby installed irb consoles is fine, but i need to specify 'irb' in cmd.exe and have it use 1.9.2 instead of the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you specify it as an argument on the command line

```
 jruby --1.9 -v
```

Don't know about the compatibility issues.

Comment: @srboisvert: Thanks for the feedback. This works fine to launch jruby at command prompt. How to specify the same in warble.rb?

Comment: I think @srboisvert got it right. I tried this approach to get irb running with 1.9. This worked: jruby --1.9 irb. This is shown on the jruby doc site: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/GettingStarted.

Answer (score 2):

I follow configuration guide of JRuby https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/ConfiguringJRuby and it work.

- Create .jrubyrc in user directory (C:\Users\tvo1510 on Window 7) with content:
  **compat.version=1.9**

It's done.
Cheers,

Comment: You can also put this file in project dir to have 1.9 in development.

Answer (score 0):

in config/warble.rb, look for this line:

```
# config.webxml.jruby.compat.version = "1.9"
```

uncomment it and re-run warble.